# Residue of $\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+4z+5}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I need to find the residue of $\dfrac{e^{iz}}{z^2+4z+5}$ at its singular points. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you already calculate the singular points?

Comment: Yes, I did. They are $-2+i$ adnd $-2-i$.

Comment: What can you say about these points? Is it a removable singularity, a pole, an essential singularity?

Hint: at a simple pole $a$ the residue of $f$ can be calculated via $$\operatorname{Res}(f,a)=\lim\limits_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)$$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$f:D\rightarrow\mathbb C,~ z\mapsto\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+4z+5}$$
With $$z^2+4z+5=(z-(-2+i))(z-(-2-i))$$ and $$e^{i\cdot(-2+i)}=e^{-2i-1}\neq 0,~e^{i\cdot(-2-i)}=e^{-2i+1}\neq 0$$ we have that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C\setminus\{-2\pm i\}$ and $f$ has simple poles at $z=-2\pm i$. As pointed out for a simple pole we can use $$\operatorname{Res}(f,a)=\lim\limits_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z).$$

For $a=-2-i$ we get: $$\operatorname{Res}(f,-2-i)=\lim\limits_{z\to -2-i} (z-(-2-i))\cdot \frac{e^{iz}}{(z-(-2+i))(z-(-2-i))}=\lim\limits_{z\to -2-i}\frac{e^{iz}}{z-(-2+i)}=\frac{e^{i\cdot(-2-i)}}{-2-i-(-2+i)}=\frac{e^{-2i+1}}{-2i}=\frac{1}{2}ie^{1-2i}$$

The other residue can be calculated in a similar way.